# Is there an open source implementation of the quotient filter?

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filter

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_filter . I did not find a single implementation yet, and I'd like something to play with, the Wikipedia explanation is a little dry for my taste.

Comment: I think you should read Bender's paper.  Just from the definition of AMQ on wikipedia, it should be clear that a Bloom filter is an AMQ already, so pick any Bloom filter implementation

Comment: Both bloom filters and quotient filters are examples of AMQs (approximate membership query), but they use different data structures for their implementation. Both are suitable for main-memory, but quotient filters are way more suited for flash SSDs according to the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a quotient filter in C ([link](https://github.com/vedantk/quotient-filter)). It supports the following operations;

- Insert(qf, key)
- May-Contain(qf, key)
- Remove(qf, key) (with a caveat, see the documentation in qf.h)
- Merge(qf1, qf2) -> qfout
- Iterate(qf)

The repository contains some documentation and a fairly rigorous test suite.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented one in PHP for the purpose of playing around with it.  It's not complete but add/contains is implemented.  This is not fool proof or even bug proof.

https://github.com/dsx724/php-quotient-filter

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which reference (paper?) did you use for this implementation?

Comment: This is off the Bender paper with the 3 bit fingerprint.  I split the fingerprint and the remainder into two different data structures for simplicity but in essence, it's the same.  I did not sort the remainders as indicated by the paper.